# uint256 value is not exactly same that i initialised

Tags: smartcontracts, ganache

I deployed a smart contract includes a state uint256 value `uint256 public cost=1000000000000000000;`. But when, after deploy, i see the storage of that smart contract value `cost:uint1441171407640000`. Why both are not equal together.

Contract state variables:

```
string public fullname; 
string public id;
bool public KYC;
uint public level;
uint256 public cost=1000000000000000000;
address payable[] public onboarded;
uint256 public arrayLength=0;
string public bankName;
bytes32 public docsHash;
```

Storage presented by Ganache:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjbrm.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better answered at [ethereum.se].